# How to display some positions in map

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps

How can i have some postitions in a map based is multi input values e.x:

I use this script to obtain a map which i display later in a div.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //------- Google Maps ---------//

    // Creating a LatLng object containing the coordinate for the center of the map

    var lat = document.getElementById('userLat').value;
        var lng = document.getElementById('userLng').value;

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);


    // Creating an object literal containing the properties we want to pass to the map  
    var options = {  
        zoom: 15, // This number can be set to define the initial zoom level of the map
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // This value can be set to define the map type ROADMAP/SATELLITE/HYBRID/TERRAIN
    };  
    // Calling the constructor, thereby initializing the map  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), options);  

    // Define Marker properties
    var imageuser = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/pinfrend.png',
        // This marker is 129 pixels wide by 42 pixels tall.
        new google.maps.Size(38, 38),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 18,42.
        new google.maps.Point(18, 38)
    );

    var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('img/pinuser.png',
        // This marker is 129 pixels wide by 42 pixels tall.
        new google.maps.Size(38, 38),
        // The origin for this image is 0,0.
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 18,42.
        new google.maps.Point(18, 38)
    );

    // Add Marker to display multi positions


    var frendlat = document.getElementById('frendLat').value;
        var frendlng = document.getElementById('frendLng').value;

    var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(frendlat, frendlng), 
        map: map,       
        icon: imageuser // This path is the custom pin to be shown. Remove this line and the proceeding comma to use default pin
    }); 

    var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng), 
        map: map,       
        icon: image // This path is the custom pin to be shown. Remove this line and the proceeding comma to use default pin
    }); 

    // Add listener for a click on the pin
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {  
        infowindow1.open(map, marker1);  
    });

    // Add information window
    var infowindow1 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({  
        content:  createInfo('Evoluted New Media', 'Ground Floor,<br />35 Lambert Street,<br />Sheffield,<br />South Yorkshire,<br />S3 7BH<br /><a href="http://www.evoluted.net" title="Click to view our website">Our Website</a>')
    }); 

    // Create information window
    function createInfo(title, content) {
        return '<div class="infowindow"><strong>'+ title +'</strong><br />'+content+'</div>';
    } 

});
```

I have the below input values:

```
<input id="userLat" type="text" name="val-lat" value="41.3275" />
<input id="userLat" type="text" name="val-lat" value="40.5486" />
<input id="userLat" type="text" name="val-lat" value="41.9637" />

<input id="userLng" type="text" name="val-lng" value="19.8189" />
<input id="userLng" type="text" name="val-lng" value="19.0056" />
<input id="userLng" type="text" name="val-lng" value="19.4513" />
```

Now i want to display a pin in a map for each userLat + userLng.

How can i archive this result?

I have tried with this script but i am getting only one pin not three pins as i have three values.

Comment: IDs need to be unique...

Comment: No, you don't have "three" values. You've got **ONE** value, because you're using duplicate `id`'s for your inputs. DOM ID's **MUST** be unique across the entire document.

Comment: what if i use one ID and in filled Value="" i call a table from MySql, so the ID will be one but the values will be three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have multiple elements with the same ID.  You can have multiple elements with the same class name.  If you change your input elements to use class instead of ID, you can get an array of the elements by using getElementsByClassName:

HTML:

```
<input class="userLat" type="text" value="41.3275" />
<input class="userLat" type="text" value="40.5486" />
<input class="userLat" type="text" value="41.9637" />

<input class="userLng" type="text" value="19.8189" />
<input class="userLng" type="text" value="19.0056" />
<input class="userLng" type="text" value="19.4513" />
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    //------- Google Maps ---------//
    var markers = [] ;
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    function createMarker(latlng) {
      bounds.extend(latlng);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latlng
      }); 
      markers.push(marker);
    }

    var lat = document.getElementsByClassName('userLat');
    var lng = document.getElementsByClassName('userLng');

    for (var i=0; (i<lat.length && i< lng.length); i++) {
      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat[i].value, lng[i].value);
      createMarker(latlng);
    }

    // Creating an object literal containing the properties we want to pass to the map  
    var options = {  
        zoom: 15, // This number can be set to define the initial zoom level of the map
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // This value can be set to define the map type ROADMAP/SATELLITE/HYBRID/TERRAIN
    };  
    // Calling the constructor, thereby initializing the map  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_div'), options);  
    for (var i=0; i<markers.length; i++) {
       markers[i].setMap(map);
    }
    // center and zoom the map to show the markers
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

[working example](http://geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_jqueryMultipleMarkers.html)

Comment: One more help, how to insert in the script you provide a Pin which will show the current user location?

Answer (score 0):

try this,hope you will understand,**google map marker for multiple pin out example,you can populate lat,long through array**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head> 
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" /> 
  <title>Google Maps Multiple Markers</title> 
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
  <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
</head> 
<body>
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 400px;"></div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    // Define your locations: HTML content for the info window, latitude, longitude
    var locations = [
      ['<h4>Bondi Beach</h4>', -33.890542, 151.274856],
      ['<h4>Coogee Beach</h4>', -33.923036, 151.259052],
      ['<h4>Cronulla Beach</h4>', -34.028249, 151.157507],
      ['<h4>Manly Beach</h4>', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187],
      ['<h4>Maroubra Beach</h4>', -33.950198, 151.259302]
    ];

    // Setup the different icons and shadows
    var iconURLPrefix = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/';

    var icons = [
      iconURLPrefix + 'red-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'green-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'blue-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'orange-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'purple-dot.png',
      iconURLPrefix + 'pink-dot.png',      
      iconURLPrefix + 'yellow-dot.png'
    ]
    var icons_length = icons.length;


    var shadow = {
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(15,33),
      url: iconURLPrefix + 'msmarker.shadow.png'
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-37.92, 151.25),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: false,
      streetViewControl: false,
      panControl: false,
      zoomControlOptions: {
         position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
      }
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      maxWidth: 160
    });

    var marker;
    var markers = new Array();

    var iconCounter = 0;

    // Add the markers and infowindows to the map
    for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map,
        icon : icons[iconCounter],
        shadow: shadow
      });

      markers.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));

      iconCounter++;
      // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so we may have to restart the counter
      if(iconCounter >= icons_length){
        iconCounter = 0;
      }
    }

    function AutoCenter() {
      //  Create a new viewpoint bound
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      //  Go through each...
      $.each(markers, function (index, marker) {
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
      });
      //  Fit these bounds to the map
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
    AutoCenter();
  </script> 
</body>
</html>
```